# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova Windows 10 Build Errors

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, win-universal-app

I'm developing a Windows Phone app using Visual Studio 2015 and Cordova 5.1.1.  I'm on a Windows 10 machine.  I ran the app in the Windows 10 Emulator once, then switched to Release mode and attempted to create a build package for the store, which failed.  Now, even in Debug mode, I can't build, let alone run, the app.  I keep getting the following errors:

[image]

When I change the Windows Target Platform to Windows 8.1, and try to build with the Emulator 8.1 WVGA, I get the following errors:
[image]

It can be noted that I'm selecting Windows Phone (Universal) from the solution configuration window.

I've restarted my computer, and that didn't change anything.

I've cleared the Cordova Cache, and that didn't fix anything for me either.

I've attempted to clean the project and the solution, but get the following errors:
[image]

**Edit**

My build platform is Windows Phone (Universal).
[image]

The plugins I'm using are `cordova-plugin-media`, which installed `cordova-plugin-file`.  It looks like `cordova-plugin-whitelist` is in my plugins directory also, but I don't remember putting it there, can't say if it's there by default or if it's a dependency.

**EDIT**

Here is a copy/paste from my output window:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PCFCordovaAppV2, Configuration: Debug Windows-AnyCPU ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.4 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.4
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\bld\Windows-AnyCPU\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\bin\Windows-AnyCPU\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Windows-AnyCPU
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: windows
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: PCFCordovaAppV2
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Johnie Karr\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------    changeList.changedFilesIos: www\images\icons-png\arrow-u-l-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\tests\tests.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileReader.js,www\css\jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.5.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ru\plugins.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\es\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\it\README.md,www\images\icons-svg\comment-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\zh\index.md,www\images\icons-png\plus-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ubuntu\file.h,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\ja\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ko\index.md,bower.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js,www\images\icons-png\eye-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\carat-r-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\heart-black.svg,www\scripts\jquery-2.1.4.min.js,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\browser\FileSystem.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\setMetadata.js,www\images\icons-svg\refresh-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\it\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\www\Media.js,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\ubuntu\media.cpp,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,www\images\icons-svg\star-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\action-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\user-white.png,www\images\icons-png\video-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\ko\index.md,www\images\icons-png\back-black.png,www\css\jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.5.min.css,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,www\images\ajax-loader.gif,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\zh\README.md,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,www\images\icons-svg\alert-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\pl\index.md,www\images\icons-png\heart-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\shop-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\browser\FileProxy.js,www\images\refreshSmall.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-d-r-black.png,www\images\playSmall.png,www\images\icons-svg\action-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ubuntu\FileWriter.js,www\images\icons-png\comment-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\DirectoryEntry.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\readAsDataURL.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,www\images\icons-svg\bullets-black.svg,www\images\play.png,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-r-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\File.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\LocalFileSystem.js,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileWriter.js,www\images\icons-png\mail-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\tests\src\android\TestContentProvider.java,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ko\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ja\index.md,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-u-r-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\EncodingException.java,www\scripts\jquery-2.1.4.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\pl\README.md,www\images\icons-png\camera-white.png,www\css\jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.min.css,www\images\icons-svg\info-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\location-white.svg,www\scripts\index.js,www\images\icons-svg\user-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\carat-d-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\de\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Metadata.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,www\images\icons-png\home-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\LocalFilesystemURL.java,www\images\icons-svg\gear-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\bars-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\remove.js,www\images\icons-png\cloud-white.png,www\images\icons-png\info-black.png,www\images\refresh.png,www\images\icons-png\check-white.png,res\icons\logo 2400x1200.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\FileUtils.java,www\images\icons-svg\back-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\minus-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\search-black.svg,www\css\jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.css,www\images\icons-svg\eye-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\arrow-u-l-black.png,www\images\icons-png\bullets-black.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\NOTICE,www\images\icons-png\star-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-d-r-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\www\browser\Media.js,www\images\icons-png\comment-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ja\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\de\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ko\plugins.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\Filesystem.java,www\images\icons-png\edit-white.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-u-r-white.png,www\css\jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css,www\images\icons-svg\recycle-white.svg,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,www\images\icons-svg\mail-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileSystem.js,www\images\icons-svg\shop-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ios\CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.m,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\de\README.md,www\images\icons-svg\heart-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\phone-black.svg,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-d-l-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ios\CDVLocalFilesystem.h,www\images\icons-svg\eye-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\android\WhitelistPlugin.java,www\images\icons-svg\carat-l-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\de\plugins.md,www\images\icons-png\grid-black.png,www\images\icons-png\search-black.png,www\images\icons-png\recycle-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ProgressEvent.js,www\images\icons-png\power-white.png,res\icons\screenshots\windows\desktop\two.png,www\images\icons-svg\home-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\write.js,www\scripts\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js,res\icons\screenshots\windows\desktop\three.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\images\icons-png\carat-r-white.png,www\images\icons-png\audio-white.png,www\images\icons-png\tag-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\requestAllFileSystems.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\plugin.xml,www\images\icons-png\grid-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\NOTICE,www\images\icons-png\forward-white.png,www\images\icons-png\action-white.png,www\css\jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.5.min.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ios\FileSystem.js,www\css\jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.5.min.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\ru\index.md,www\images\icons-svg\lock-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ubuntu\file.cpp,www\css\index.css,www\images\icons-png\star-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\calendar-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\bullets-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\navigation-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\browser\Preparing.js,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,www\images\icons-svg\minus-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\carat-u-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\mail-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\removeRecursively.js,www\images\icons-svg\info-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\tests\plugin.xml,www\images\icons-png\back-white.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\FileExistsException.java,www\scripts\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.map,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\blackberry10\index.js,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-u-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\requestFileSystem.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\wp\FileUploadOptions.js,www\images\icons-svg\power-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\LICENSE,res\native\windows\CordovaApp.pfx,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\es\index.md,www\images\icons-svg\cloud-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\README.md,www\images\icons-png\gear-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\delete-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\mail-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\carat-l-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystemPaths.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\createEntryFromNative.js,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-d-white.svg,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\whitelist.js,www\images\icons-svg\audio-black.svg,plugins\fetch.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystems.js,www\images\icons-svg\gear-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\de\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\getParent.js,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-u-white.svg,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\native\windows\Package.StoreAssociation.xml,www\images\icons-png\shop-black.png,res\icons\logo 358x358.png,www\images\icons-svg\carat-d-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\forbidden-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ios\CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.h,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\tests\plugin.xml,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\LICENSE,www\images\icons-svg\tag-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\forbidden-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\it\plugins.md,www\images\icons-png\arrow-u-r-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\moveTo.js,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-u-l-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\DirectoryReader.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ja\plugins.md,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-u-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ubuntu\FileSystem.js,www\images\icons-svg\lock-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\star-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\forbidden-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\grid-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\arrow-r-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\bars-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\CONTRIBUTING.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\requestFileSystem.js,www\images\icons-png\refresh-white.png,package.json,www\images\icons-svg\audio-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\delete-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\package.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\firefoxos\FileProxy.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileEntry.js,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\copyTo.js,www\images\icons-png\forward-black.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,www\images\icons-svg\check-white.svg,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\zh\plugins.md,www\images\icons-png\arrow-d-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\back-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\camera-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\pl\index.md,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileUploadOptions.js,www\images\icons-png\shop-white.png,www\images\icons-png\carat-r-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\user-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\forward-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\info.js,www\css\listview-grid.css,www\css\jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.5.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileUploadResult.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\tests\tests.js,www\images\icons-png\tag-white.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,www\images\icons-svg\carat-d-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\bars-white.png,www\images\icons-png\action-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\delete-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\CONTRIBUTING.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\wp\AudioPlayer.cs,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\FileSystem.js,res\icons\logo 300x300.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\fr\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\RELEASENOTES.md,www\images\icons-svg\location-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\alert-black.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\InvalidModificationException.java,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\plugin.xml,www\images\icons-svg\recycle-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\video-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\NoModificationAllowedException.java,www\images\icons-png\camera-black.png,www\images\icons-png\home-black.png,res\icons\logo 558x756.png,build.json,www\images\icons-svg\carat-r-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\requestAnimationFrame.js,www\images\icons-svg\plus-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\recycle-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-l-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\carat-l-white.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-u-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Flags.js,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\images\icons-png\phone-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\readAsText.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\fr\README.md,www\images\icons-svg\grid-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\README.md,www\images\icons-png\arrow-l-black.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,www\images\icons-svg\clock-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ios\CDVLocalFilesystem.m,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,www\images\icons-png\calendar-black.png,www\css\jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.5.css,www\images\icons-png\delete-white.png,www\images\icons-png\alert-white.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-d-l-white.png,www\images\icons-png\check-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\carat-l-black.svg,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\zh\index.md,www\images\icons-png\lock-black.png,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-d-r-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\blackberry10\index.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\package.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\CONTRIBUTING.md,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-r-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\refresh-white.svg,www\images\pauseSmall.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\android\AudioHandler.java,www\images\icons-png\plus-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\LocalFilesystem.java,www\scripts\jqueryHelpers.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\zh\README.md,www\images\icons-png\refresh-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\package.json,www\images\icons-svg\comment-black.svg,res\native\android\ant.properties,www\images\mic.png,www\images\icons-png\carat-u-black.png,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,www\images\icons-svg\forbidden-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\calendar-white.svg,res\icons\logo 1000x800.png,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-l-white.svg,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\ContentFilesystem.java,www\images\icons-svg\check-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\gear-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\AssetFilesystem.java,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\getFileMetadata.js,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\fr\plugins.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\plugins.md,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,www\images\icons-svg\alert-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-u-l-white.svg,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\wp\Media.cs,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,www\images\icons-svg\minus-black.svg,res\icons\screenshots\windows\desktop\one.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,www\images\icons-svg\cloud-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\audio-black.png,res\icons\logo 846x468.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\windows\FileProxy.js,www\scripts\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\ubuntu\media.h,www\images\icons-svg\edit-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\plus-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\tag-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\NOTICE,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\LICENSE,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\firefoxos\FileSystem.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\ja\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\readEntries.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\ios\CDVSound.h,res\icons\logo 358x173.png,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystems-roots.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\windows\MediaProxy.js,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,www\images\icons-svg\edit-black.svg,www\images\folder.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\ios\CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.h,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\build-extras.gradle,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,www\images\icons-svg\power-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ubuntu\fileSystems-roots.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\es\plugins.md,www\images\icons-png\clock-black.png,www\images\icons-png\heart-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\search-white.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\getDirectory.js,res\icons\logo 414x468.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-l-white.png,res\icons\logo 414x180.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\pl\plugins.md,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-d-l-white.svg,www\images\pause.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\wp\File.cs,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\ko\README.md,www\images\icons-png\power-black.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,www\images\icons-png\carat-u-white.png,res\icons\logo 558x558.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\www\MediaError.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\it\index.md,www\css\jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\es\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\doc\pl\README.md,www\images\icons-png\bullets-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\TypeMismatchException.java,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\android\DirectoryManager.java,www\css\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\fr\index.md,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-u-r-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\eye-black.png,www\images\icons-png\arrow-r-black.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,www\images\icons-svg\phone-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\arrow-d-l-black.png,www\images\icons-png\location-black.png,www\images\icons-png\navigation-white.png,www\images\icons-png\calendar-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\ios\CDVSound.m,www\images\icons-png\arrow-d-r-white.png,www\images\icons-png\carat-d-white.png,www\images\icons-svg\camera-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\search-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\android\FileSystem.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,www\images\icons-png\phone-black.png,www\images\icons-png\user-black.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,www\images\icons-svg\carat-u-black.svg,www\images\icons-svg\home-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\truncate.js,www\images\icons-svg\video-black.svg,www\images\icons-png\navigation-black.png,www\css\jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\android\AudioPlayer.java,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\FileProxy.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\android\FileHelper.java,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,www\images\icons-png\bars-black.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Entry.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\fr\README.md,www\images\icons-png\info-white.png,www\images\icons-png\minus-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\getFile.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileError.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\es\README.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\ru\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\RELEASENOTES.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\tizen\MediaProxy.js,www\images\icons-svg\video-white.svg,www\images\icons-svg\arrow-d-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\doc\it\index.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ios\CDVFile.m,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\ios\CDVFile.h,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\readAsArrayBuffer.js,www\images\icons-png\arrow-d-black.png,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\RELEASENOTES.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\ios\CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.m,www\images\icons-png\lock-white.png,www\images\icons-png\location-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\readAsBinaryString.js,www\css\jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\README.md,www\images\icons-svg\navigation-black.svg,plugins\cordova-plugin-media\plugin.xml,www\images\icons-png\cloud-black.png,www\images\icons-png\clock-white.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\blackberry10\getMetadata.js,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,www\images\icons-svg\clock-black.svg,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png,www\images\icons-svg\forward-white.svg,www\images\icons-png\edit-black.png,www\css\jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.css,config.xml
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Platform windows already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\res\native\windows to platforms\windows
1>  ------ Copied C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\res\native\windows\CordovaApp.pfx to platforms\windows\CordovaApp.pfx
1>  ------ Copied C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\res\native\windows\Package.StoreAssociation.xml to platforms\windows\Package.StoreAssociation.xml
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\windows
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0,cordova-plugin-media@1.0.2-dev
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins: cordova-plugin-file@2.1.0
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: windows
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "windows"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "windows"
1>  Preparing windows project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'cordova-plugin-whitelist',
1>    'cordova-plugin-media',
1>    'cordova-plugin-file' ]
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  ------ Copied C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\bin\Windows-AnyCPU\Debug\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Metadata.Overrides.props to platforms\windows\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Metadata.Overrides.props
1>  ------ Building platform: windows
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat" --debug --archs=anycpu --win "--buildConfig=C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\build.json"""
1>  Reading build config file: C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\build.json
1>  MSBuildToolsPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\
1>  Building project: C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
1>      Configuration : debug
1>      Platform      : anycpu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(188,5): error MSB4062: The "IlcErrorTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\ilc.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x86\ilc\ilc.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>MDAVSCLI : error : Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\msbuild with args: C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=anycpu
1>  Command finished with error code 2: cmd /s /c ""C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\platforms\windows\cordova\build.bat" --debug --archs=anycpu --win "--buildConfig=C:\My Applications\PCF\PCFCordovaAppV2\PCFCordovaAppV2\build.json""
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**UPDATE**
After performing a `Repair` of `Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova`, this problem persists.

**UPDATE**
After performing a `Repair` of Visual Studio, the problem still persists.

**UPDATE, 08/31/2015**
I created a brand new project, and found the problem only persists AFTER, I attempt to associate with an app in the store from Solution Explorer.

**UPDATE, 09/03/2015**
Seems to be any interaction with the Store menu.  See this ~2minute video demonstration: http://1drv.ms/1POH9Qk

Comment: Can you outline which plugins you're using?

Comment: Can you also share your build platform (x86/x64/arm)?

Comment: @Rob, I've edited my question to address your answers, though, I'm not sure how to tell my build platform other than it's the Windows Phone (Universal) selection.  I assume that's arm.

Comment: I've updated the Build Errors image (the first image) to include the entire error window, if those details help any.

Comment: It's weird that you're running into an ILC error because ILC is the .NET Native compiler, and looking at your plugin list, you don't have any plugins which depend on a .NET component.  Can you share your actual build output (from the Output window) instead of the Error List?

Comment: I decided I would start a new Cordova app, so I went to new project, but under JavaScript, I no longer have an option for Apache Cordova.  I'll reinstall Visual Studio along with Cordova tools and see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: FYI: I did a repair of Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova and the Cordova Application template returned to the new project window, but this build problem still persists.  I'm trying a repair of Visual Studio now.  @Rob, have you any other ideas by chance?

Comment: A repair of Visual Studio didn't fix anything either.

Comment: If you select a specific platform (such as x86 if you're targeting an emulator), does that enable you to build?  What version of cordova-windows are you using?  I'm assuming 4.0.0?  (Find in your project's `platforms\windows\VERSION` file).

Comment: x64 and Local Machine fails.  x86 and Local Machine fail also.

Comment: Moving my response to the answer below...

Comment: @Rob, I've updated my question with some more information.  I started a brand new project, and the problem doesn't start until AFTER I attempt to associate the app with the store.  Any advice is helpful.

Comment: @Rob, Seems to be any interaction with the Store menu.  See this ~2minute video demonstration: http://1drv.ms/1POH9Qk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Windows 10 appears to have solved the issue.  Installing Cordova plugins from the config designer even works now.

Comment: You had to reinstall the OS to fix this?? that's insane

Comment: I agree, but was the only solution I tried that worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone (Universal) is an unfortunate name that refers to the Windows 8.1 "Universal Project System" templates that shipped with Visual Studio 2013.  Given your list of plugins, none of which should contain any .NET, choose the `Windows-AnyCPU` platform target.  That is the Windows 10 build.

It's not really clear to me why you wouldn't be able to build from Debug to Release, but let's start with that change and go forward.  Note that you should select the correct deployment emulator target from the Play dropdown.  But to me it sounded like you were building a Windows 10 app, i.e., config.xml specifies `windows-target-version` of 10.0; and in that case, the Windows Phone (Universal) project is invalid.

**Update:**

Can you try this out and report the results from a Node.js command line?

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform remove windows
cordova platform add windows@https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/cordova/CB-9447/cordova-windows-4.1.0.tgz
```

This is the current Cordova release candidate for Cordova-Windows 4.1.0.  Cordova-Windows 4.1.0 is targeted to support Windows 10 RTM.  I suspect the addition of .NET Native in VS 2015 RTM is what is causing the problem; 4.0.0 supported Windows 10 RC.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  I assumed that since I could select the Windows Target Version of 8.1 or 10 from the config.xml designer that I could build this app to support WP 8.1 and also WP 10.  I'll switch the target version back to 10.0 and choose Windows-AnyCPU and let you know.

Comment: This gives me the same result as in the OP.  
`Debug`, `Windows-AnyCPU`, `Local Machine`, `Windows Target Version: 10.0`  `Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch 512MB` also same result.

Comment: Is it a bug in Visual Studio that I have the option for the Windows Phone 10 emulators when Windows Phone (Universal) is selected?

Comment: The build still fails, same error.  When I did `npm install -g cordova`, it completed, but I did get this warning `npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"})`

Comment: The remove and add windows commands completed with no problems, and I verified the version file said 4.1.0

Comment: From the command line, what if you enter `cordova run windows -- --debug --win`?  (Might also need to add `--appx=uap` if you're building for Windows 10).  Run from the project directory.

Comment: I get the same error.  I tried both with and without the `--appx=uap` switch and got the same result both times